Lexplore opens in wrong directory
I'm running into a problem where Lexplore opens with directory of the "top left" most window, even when the cursor is in a different window (see diagram).
How do I get Lexplore to open with the directory of the file of the window the cursor is currently in?
Bonus points if you can figure out how to have Lexplore open a new file in the window that Lexplore was called from.


I'm afraid I'm not sure to understand what is your question. What are the actions that you have taken to come with the initial layout (and what it is exactly)? What is the action you perform to come to second layout (and what it is exactly)? What result you would like to have and why the result you have is not what you like?

The Lexplore doesn't change the layout in my tests. Maybe could you share a minimal init.vim configuration that lead to the behavior you mention such that we could reproduce your problem.

Lexplore uses the pwd by default, I believe.

While I didn't solve the exact problem I mentioned, I was able to minorly modify my workflow to achieve the desired affect.
Instead of using Lexplore to navigate the file system, I just call :e. from the window I want to change (as outlined in this article.
This has the desired effect of opening netrw in the correct directory.
